# Implicit declaration of function glGenFramebuffers

Tags: ios, opengl-es

Just getting started with Xcode and Open GL and I am getting 
"Implicit declaration of function glGenFramebuffers" in my GL View class. I am importing

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
```

And I also tried with

```
#import <OpenGLES/EAGL.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/gl.h>
#import <OpenGLES/ES1/glext.h>
```

and make clean all targets but the warning stays! What does it mean? What do I have to import for it to go away?

Comment: The code I am trying to run is not drawing anything yet it's just the code from the apple open gl guide that sets up things.

Comment: Try importing `<OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h>` in your precompiled header file '.pch'. The error means that the compiler can't find the function declaration.

Comment: @ValentinRadu If I do that I get a linker error saying symbols not found. I am actually including that gl.h in the .h file of the class where I'm getting the errors.

Comment: @ValentinRadu Actually, now that I did what the answer says I get "  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAEAGLLayer", referenced from:

", too.

Comment: I had to add QuartzCore to Frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import `OpenGLES/ES2/gl.h`, the `glGenFramebuffers` function is not available in OpenGL ES 1. If you actually want to use OpenGL ES 1 you need to use `glGenFramebuffersOES` which is part of the OES_framebuffer_object extension.

Comment: Haha, that completely resolves my puzzlement, thank you so much!